# not updating photon by updated nominatim data

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim, geocoder

I have a problem with photon. I had already imported data to nominatim db.

afterwards, I imported data to photon based on new imported data from nominatim.
but for some reason I was forced to empty nominatim db and imported new data to it, and then updated photon. but the problem is that there is old indexed data on photon yet.
I thought that by this command is updated photon data :
        curl http://localhost:2322/nominatim-update

I saw this error after running this command :

```java
Exception in thread "Thread-200" org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestValidationException: Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ValidateActions.addValidationError(ValidateActions.java:29)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequest.validate(BulkRequest.java:600)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:131)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:84)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:83)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:72)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:408)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:80)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:54)
    at de.komoot.photon.elasticsearch.Updater.updateDocuments(Updater.java:64)
    at de.komoot.photon.elasticsearch.Updater.finish(Updater.java:30)
    at de.komoot.photon.nominatim.NominatimUpdater.update(NominatimUpdater.java:65)
    at de.komoot.photon.App.lambda$null$0(App.java:152)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

but seems this command doesn`t work correctly.
I followed by all instructions written in this link:
    https://github.com/komoot/photon

please let me know how can i fix this issue?

Comment: cross-post: https://github.com/komoot/photon/issues/415. Also did you notice https://github.com/komoot/photon/issues/229?